# std::tuple equivalent of std::pair's second member?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std-pair, stdtuple

I'm converting this function to use `std::tuple` which does not have `first` and `second` memebers like `std:pair`.

```
std::type_index argumentType(const std::string& name) const
{
    return std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),
        [&name](std::pair<std::string, std::type_index> arg)->bool
        {
            return arg.first == name;
        }
    )->second;
}
```

I'm confused by the syntax `->second`, what is this doing? and is thre equivalent `std::get<1>(arg)`

```
std::type_index argType(const std::string& name) const
{
    return std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),
        [&name](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Attribute> arg)->bool
        {
            return std::get<0>(arg) == name;
        }
    )std::get<1>(arg);
```

Example 2:

std::pair

```
bool hasArg(const std::string& name) const
{
    return std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),
        [&name](std::pair<std::string, std::type_index> arg)->bool
        {
            return arg.first == name;
        }
    ) != args_.end();
}
```

std::tuple

```
bool hasArg(const std::string& name) const
{
    return std::get<0>(*std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),
        [&name](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Attribute> arg)->bool
        {
            return std::get<0>(arg) == name;
        }
    )) != args_.end();
}
```

Comment: maybe isn't useful for you but... if you want to write a common code that works for `std::tuple` and `std::pair` (also `std::array`, if you want) you can use `std::get()` also for pairs; so, for a `p` object of a `std::pair` type, you can use `std::get<0>(p)` instead of `p.first`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::find_if` returns an iterator to a pair, that's why you need to use the arrow operator `->`, which the iterator has overloaded to return a reference to the actual value for purposes of member access.

Yes, `std::get<1>` for a tuple will do pretty much the same, but the syntax will be different:

```
auto it = std::find_if(...);
return std::get<1>(*it);
```

You need to use the dereference operator `*` instead of the arrow operator, because `std::get` is a free function and not a tuple's member.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout documentation of [std::find_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/)

So `std::find_if` will return iterator. In code #1 it was [iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) to pair, so `->second` will husk `second` element of [std::pair](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair). You use [-> overloaded operator for iterator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator-%3E/).

Example:

```
auto it = std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),...);
if(it != args_.end()) // This is important to NOT dereference iterator if it is pointing to end
{
    // also you can write (*it).second; (first use dereference operator)
    return it->second;
}
// ...
```

So in you case you should refactor it to:

```
std::type_index argType(const std::string& name) const
{
    // Please don't do so much in 1 line. Compiler will optimize this for you :)
    // Please check for std::end, this is potential dangerous.
    return std::get<1>(*std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),
        [&name](std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Attribute> arg)->bool
        {
            return std::get<0>(arg) == name;
        }
    ));
}
```

Same example:

```
auto it = std::find_if(args_.begin(), args_.end(),...);
if(it != args_.end()) // This is important to NOT dereference iterator if it is pointing to end
{
    return std::get<1>(*it);
}
// ...
```

---

**Important**

Please also consider case when you don't find your element. `std::find_if` will return `std::end(args_)` if element you are looking for doesn't exist. So calling `->second` or `std::get<1>(*it)` [is undefinied behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965621/behavior-when-dereferencing-the-end-of-a-vector-of-strings) and can crush.

---

Fix for `hasArg` function. Now you don't need dereference your iterator.

```
bool hasArg(const std::string& name) const
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(args_), std::end(args_),
        [&name](const std::tuple<std::string, std::type_index, Attribute>& arg)->bool
        {
            return std::get<0>(arg) == name;
        }
    ) != std::end(args_);
}
```

In this solution I used [std::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end). This is more uniwersal way instead calling `arg_.begin()` :)

Please check how I ficed syntax of your second example. 
One last thing, when you use `std::find_if` and lambda to find what you are looking for, argument should be `const&` in most cases :), because we don't want to make a copy here.

Comment: many thanks for you explanation. I am reading about `std::find()`. I've posted a second example in my original question following your advice however it is not correct, could you suggest what I've done wrong? thank you

Comment: @cherryaldi I added fix for your second example. If it still doesn't work please give more information what isn't working ? Maybe add compilation errors.