# store a pointers to element that inside a fixed size vector

Tags: c++, iterator, stdvector

I can't convince myself that it is safe to store a pointer to a vector.end() 
(i.e whatever vector end() iterator returns)

Data is

```
std::vector<unsigned char> data;
```

```
auto end = &(*data.end());
block b(end, size);
blocks.push_back(b);
data.insert(data.end(), (unsigned char*) ptr_data, (unsigned char*) ptr_data + size);
```

My question is. Can this address change ( &*(data.end() ), with a condition that vector capacity pre-allocate and the client will never insert more than vector supposes to store.

So it should be a continuous region in memory, so my assumption that vector will not do any memove operation and therefore I can store pointers that will point to different elements.
(so here block store a pointer to whatever data.end() point to (before insertion to data vector) 
and metadata about variable size data inside that data vector.

Thank you.

Comment: `auto end = &(*data.end())` -- It is undefined behavior to dereference the `end` iterator.  For example, this code causes an `assert()` to fire when run under Visual Studio.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965621/behavior-when-dereferencing-the-end-of-a-vector-of-strings)

Comment: Just store the offset instead of a pointer or iterator and you won't have to worry about it

Comment: Instead of `auto end = &(*data.end());` use `auto end = data.data() + data.size();`

Comment: that was a concern  : ( I guess it all depends on how vector pre-allocate capacity. if memory pre-allocated at given capacity by the allocator, it shouldn't point to something outside)

Comment: @Kevin you right it probably a better solution. But I was not really sure about invalidation for fixed capacity vector.   Vector does own memory management so I was not sure what it guarantees.

Answer (score 3):

It should be safe to store an iterator such as `std::vector::end()`as long as it doesn't get [invalidated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438086/10957435). There is a long list of rules for invalidation, but the gist of it (as it relates to your example) is that doing this is okay, until you hit `push_back()`:

```
blocks.push_back(b);
```

This call invalidates the iterator because it adjusts its size. You will need to get `blocks.end()` again for it to be valid.

---

One thing to note is that you probably shouldn't be dereferencing `end()` though. [It is unsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26965621/10957435). However, the use case you have is very similar to [this problem with regular arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3144904/10957435). That addresses regular arrays, an not vectors, but I'd imagine it'd be very similar.

The long story short is if you take the address of the 1 past end of the array element, it may or may be considered undefined behavior and is considered by some as a defect in the standard.

Instead, you don't really need to store the address of the dereferenced iterator, just store the iterator:

```
auto end = data.end();
```

Iterators are designed to work similarly to pointers, so there is no real reason to get the address of one here.

Comment: oh man that link is amazing, I was going over STL Vector code to figure out this rule :))

Comment: It shouldn't be safe.  It is undefined behavior to dereference the `end()` iterator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Didn't mean to say dereferencing it is okay. Updated to be more clear with my meaning.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I think I fixed it now.